# filter data flatlist with react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, filter, searchbar

I have a SearchBar component that allows me to filter my data from my flatlist but that on the name field I would like to make it evolve so that it filters on the name field and the first name field how could I do that?
thank you in advance.

```
  handleSearch = (searchText) => {
    if (searchText) {
      setState({ searchText: searchText });

      const filteredData = profil.filter((item) => {
        const itemData = item.data.name;
        const textData = searchText.toUpperCase();

        return itemData.includes(textData);
      });
      setFilterData(filteredData);
      setState({ query: searchText });
    } else {
      setFilterData(profil);
      setState({ query: searchText });
    }
  };
```

Comment: Can you please explain you issue further ?

Comment: currently I search by name and I would now like to search by name or first name so no longer search on 1 field but two, I want to filter on my name and my first name

Answer (score 0):

You could do this (declare a new variable for what you're searching for and then modify your return statement):

```
const firstNameData = item.data.firstName;
```

...

```
return itemData.includes(textData) || firstNameData.includes(textData);
```